# Electrum wallet giving dust error even for larger amount

Tags: electrum

I have used this wallet sever times before to send or receive. I closed, downloaded and tried again to send to multiple addresses.
Error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK47s.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Please try switching servers using the Network option or the green dot button in the bottom-right. Try making the same payment from a different server.

Answer (score 1):

The dust threshold depends on the min relay fee, which is a server setting.
Thus, it is server dependent. At this point, this threshold is not sent by the Electrum server to the client, but it is a default value, hardcoded in the client. That default value might be lower than the value set by the server you are using. Try to use another server.